# PHP MySQL Query - Array places data into one column in table , wanting two columns in the table

Tags: php, arrays

I have a query, it is outputting the results into one column, I would like to have the results shown in two columns. Here is the code:

```
$i = 0; 
$columnCount = 2;
echo "<table>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    { 
        $newRow = ( $i % $columnCount == 0 );      
        if( $newRow ) {         
        echo '<tr>';      
        }      
        echo '<td>' . $row['text'] . '</td>';      
        if( $newRow ) {           
        echo '</tr>';      
        }      
        $i++;  
    }
echo "</table>";
```

Thanks Again,

Comment: Do you want the data to go vertical first, or horizontal first?

Answer (score 1):

You are only defining a single column in your script.  Change:

```
echo '<td>' . $row['text'] . '</td>';
```

to:

```
echo '<td>' . $row['text'] . '</td><td>' . $row['othercolumn'] . '</td>';
```

Also I don't think your tests for defined a new row are necessary unless you want to alternate `tr` definitions so the following will work:

```
echo '<tr><td>' . $row['text'] . '</td><td>' . $row['othercolumn'] . '</td></tr>';
```

or if you really want different rows do:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    if ( $i % 2 == 0 ) {
        echo '<tr class="red">';
    } else {
        echo '<tr class="blue">';
    }
    echo '<td>' . $row['text'] . '</td><td>' . $row['othercolumn'] . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0; 
$columnCount = 2;
echo "<table>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    { 

        if( $i % $columnCount == 0 ) {   
           if( $i != 0 ){      
             echo '</tr><tr>'; 
           else{
              echo '<tr>';
           }     
        }

        echo '<td>' . $row['text'] . '</td>';      

        $i++;  
    }
echo "</table>";
```